# How do I license my design without registering copyright?

Tags: copyright

A new T-shirt business would like to use my design for which I did not register a copyright officially but as far as I understand, under the international law, as the original creator of the content, I will be the copyright owner. So how will the process of licensing the design to the business be like(for a percentage royalty on the revenue). So how should the licensing process be like?

Comment: Where do you live? Where is the companys headquater? I think best would be to ask an lawer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A contract about the terms you agreed upon should be more than enough.